# PyGreSQL Run SQL interactively

Tags: psql, greenplum, pygresql

I have a GreenPlum database, and I'm trying to create several external tables.

I'm using the `PyGreSQL` package to interface with the database.

However, I can't escape `\i` (or `\dt`, `\du`, `\dv`).

`db.query("\i h1/ext/eng/ext_eng" + i + ".sql")`

`pg.ProgrammingError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"`

I've tried `"\\i"`, `" '\i' "` and other combinations.

Comment: I figured out how to do it using [this](http://superuser.com/questions/701415/how-do-i-execute-run-a-sql-file-in-postgresql-9-2-6-centos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain those aliases can be used by generic clients.

You can avoid `\i` by first reading the file `h1/ext/eng/ext_eng.sql` with Python, then streaming the resulting SQL text to PyGreSQL with `db.query()`.

As for \dt, \du, and \dv - the SQL equivalents can be see by running `\set ECHO_HIDDEN` from a psql prompt, then issuing each to see the true definition. I've included the result below.

\dt:

```
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  c.relname as "Name",
  CASE c.relkind WHEN 'r' THEN 'table' WHEN 'v' THEN 'view' WHEN 'i' THEN 'index' WHEN 'S' THEN 'sequence' WHEN 's' THEN 'special' END as "Type",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(c.relowner) as "Owner", CASE c.relstorage WHEN 'h' THEN 'heap' WHEN 'x' THEN 'external' WHEN 'a' THEN 'append only' WHEN 'v' THEN 'none' WHEN 'c' THEN 'append only columnar' WHEN 'p' THEN 'parquet' WHEN 'f' THEN 'foreign' END as "Storage"

FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE c.relkind IN ('r','')
AND c.relstorage IN ('h', 'a', 'c', 'p','')
      AND n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
      AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
      AND n.nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
  AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

\du:

```
SELECT r.rolname, r.rolsuper, r.rolinherit,
  r.rolcreaterole, r.rolcreatedb, r.rolcanlogin,
  r.rolconnlimit,
  ARRAY(SELECT b.rolname
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_auth_members m
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_roles b ON (m.roleid = b.oid)
        WHERE m.member = r.oid) as memberof
FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles r
ORDER BY 1;
```

\dv:

```
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  c.relname as "Name",
  CASE c.relkind WHEN 'r' THEN 'table' WHEN 'v' THEN 'view' WHEN 'i' THEN 'index' WHEN 'S' THEN 'sequence' WHEN 's' THEN 'special' END as "Type",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(c.relowner) as "Owner", CASE c.relstorage WHEN 'h' THEN 'heap' WHEN 'x' THEN 'external' WHEN 'a' THEN 'append only' WHEN 'v' THEN 'none' WHEN 'c' THEN 'append only columnar' WHEN 'p' THEN 'parquet' WHEN 'f' THEN 'foreign' END as "Storage"

FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE c.relkind IN ('v','')
AND c.relstorage IN ('v','')
      AND n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
      AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
      AND n.nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
  AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

It's not ideal, but you can replace the \d references with these code equivalents.